# Array Combine Problem

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem..
i want to combine two array..

multidimensional

Array 1.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 2
        [4] => 1
     )
```

Array 2

```
        Array
        (
            [0] => asdf
            [1] => asdfa
            [2] => asdf
            [3] => asdf
            [4] => asdfasdf
        )
```

I need solution like this...

```
        Array
        (
            [1] => asdf
            [2] => asdfa
            [1] => asdf
            [2] => asdf
            [1] => asdfasdf
        )
```

If there is any solution in multidimensional array please let me know.

After combine both array i need to use with foreach or any method and i want to insert array data in Database

Like this..

```
        ID | Value    | S_ID
        --------------------
        1  | asdf     |  1
        2  | asdfa    |  2
        3  | asdf     |  1
        4  | asdf     |  2
        4  | asdfasdf |  1
```

I so confused and i try lot of function and method from last 6 hours but no luck :(..

Comment: The second array would be impossible, since you have keys which are the same, which would not be possible.

Comment: It is not possible to combine the arrays as you explain in the first place, because arrays cannot have duplicate keys; otherwise, [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) would do the job. Think about alternatives.

Comment: is there any possibility i could combine both array in multidimensional?

Comment: yes i know i can't combine array like this but is there any solution please let me know.. but i n my mind i could do that with some thing like this..
Array
        (
            [0] => asdf|1
            [1] => asdfa|2
            [2] => asdf|1
            [3] => asdf|2
            [4] => asdfasdf|1
        )
How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the two arrays together and create a multidimensional array:

```
$newarray = array();

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $newarray[] = array(
        'Value' => $value,
        'S_ID' => $array2[$key],
    );
}

print_r($newarray);
```